# How to convert string to DataFrame with spaces in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is a sample string . How can i convert this string to a pandas Dataframe?

```
   str1 =
    """
    Feature Id & Feature Desc                             Status   Failed Total 
    ---------------------------------------------------   -------- ------ -----
    RKSPACE (RackSpace Test In)                           Passed   0      1     
    D1 (Drum 1 Test)                                      Passed   0      1     
    D2 (Drum 2 Test)                                      Passed   0      1     
    D3 (Drum 3 Test)                                      Passed   0      1     
    PRIMUS (PRIMUS Ink Test)                              Not-run  0      0     
    RGB (RGB Color Test)                                  Passed   0      1     
    YONO (App Test)                                       Not-run  0      0     
    PSENSE (Paper Sensor Test)                            Not-run  0      0     
    TFlag (Flag Test)                                     Not-run  0      0     
    MEMT (Memory Test)                                    Passed   0      1     
    CRG (CARRIAGE Test)                                   Not-run  0      0    
    """
```

I have tried the below code

```
    import pandas as pd
    from StringIO import StringIO        
    def get_dataframe(str1):
        test_data = StringIO(str1)
        df = pd.read_csv(test_data, sep=r'\s+', comment='--', engine='python')
        return df
```

The result I am getting is ugly and not correct.
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euYxm.jpg)
I have checked other posts, but didn't find any question that deals with spaces in the string.
Normally, if there were no spaces in the 1st column, this would have been easy to get the Dataframe, but how do I convert it to dataframe preserving the same format as the str1?
Any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
str1 = """
Feature Id & Feature Desc                             Status   Failed Total 
---------------------------------------------------   -------- ------ -----
RKSPACE (RackSpace Test In)                           Passed   0      1     
D1 (Drum 1 Test)                                      Passed   0      1     
D2 (Drum 2 Test)                                      Passed   0      1     
D3 (Drum 3 Test)                                      Passed   0      1     
PRIMUS (PRIMUS Ink Test)                              Not-run  0      0     
RGB (RGB Color Test)                                  Passed   0      1     
YONO (App Test)                                       Not-run  0      0     
PSENSE (Paper Sensor Test)                            Not-run  0      0     
TFlag (Flag Test)                                     Not-run  0      0     
MEMT (Memory Test)                                    Passed   0      1     
CRG (CARRIAGE Test)                                   Not-run  0      0    
"""
```

---

```
df = pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(str1), 
                 colspecs=[(0, 50), (51, 62), (63, 69), (70, 76)], 
                 skiprows=[2],
                 header=[1])
print (df)
      Feature Id & Feature Desc   Status  Failed  Total
0   RKSPACE (RackSpace Test In)   Passed       0      1
1              D1 (Drum 1 Test)   Passed       0      1
2              D2 (Drum 2 Test)   Passed       0      1
3              D3 (Drum 3 Test)   Passed       0      1
4      PRIMUS (PRIMUS Ink Test)  Not-run       0      0
5          RGB (RGB Color Test)   Passed       0      1
6               YONO (App Test)  Not-run       0      0
7    PSENSE (Paper Sensor Test)  Not-run       0      0
8             TFlag (Flag Test)  Not-run       0      0
9            MEMT (Memory Test)   Passed       0      1
10          CRG (CARRIAGE Test)  Not-run       0      0
```

Thanks @gyoza for simplify solution:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(str1), 
                 skiprows=[2],
                 header=[1])
print (df)
      Feature Id & Feature Desc   Status  Failed  Total
0   RKSPACE (RackSpace Test In)   Passed       0      1
1              D1 (Drum 1 Test)   Passed       0      1
2              D2 (Drum 2 Test)   Passed       0      1
3              D3 (Drum 3 Test)   Passed       0      1
4      PRIMUS (PRIMUS Ink Test)  Not-run       0      0
5          RGB (RGB Color Test)   Passed       0      1
6               YONO (App Test)  Not-run       0      0
7    PSENSE (Paper Sensor Test)  Not-run       0      0
8             TFlag (Flag Test)  Not-run       0      0
9            MEMT (Memory Test)   Passed       0      1
10          CRG (CARRIAGE Test)  Not-run       0      0
```

Comment: @gyoza - Thank you ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. When I use the exact solution as above, I am getting 'NaN' in all the rows and columns. But if I use 'header'=1 instead of 'header'=[1], it works fine. Anyway thanks for the solution again.